# Trying to make a fish command /discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

Now, I have my shop and all the items already. I want the user so when they buy the FishingRod, they get put in a `new Set();`, and once they are in that set they can use the `fish` command. Here's my code for the 'buy' command:

```
else if (command === 'buy') {
        const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(' ');

        if (isDead.has(message.author.id)) {
            message.channel.send('You\'re dead right now lmao you need to wait 5 more minutes before using any more currency and game related commands');
        }
        const item = await CurrencyShop.findOne({ where: { name: { [Op.like]: commandArgs } } });
        if (!item) return message.channel.send('That item doesn\'t exist.');
        if (args === 'FishingRod') {
            hasRod.add(message.author.id);
        }
        if (item.cost > currency.getBalance(message.author.id)) {
            return message.channel.send(`You don't have enough currency, ${message.author}`);
        }
        const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: message.author.id } });
        currency.add(message.author.id, -item.cost);
        await user.addItem(item);

        message.channel.send(`You've bought a ${item.name}`);
    }
```

As you can see, I've already made it so when the args are 'FishingRod', it puts them in the Set. The problem is that when this happens, and I try running the `fish` command, it still says I haven't got a FishingRod and need to buy one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're trying to compare the command arguments (which is an array) to a string. You could just do `args[0]` to get the first argument. Also, you're making it so that it has to be "FishingRod" and can't be lowercase. Try `args[0].toLowerCase() === "fishingrod"`.

Comment: it still says `You don't have a rod, buy one at the shop`

Comment: there's another problem -- if you store your data in a Set then all data will be cleared on bot restart

Comment: also I'm not really sure how it still says you don't have a rod, since I don't have context

Comment: So do I use a map instead?

Comment: Or what should I use instead of a Set?